# Printer Argox PPLA

Tags: java

I'm having trouble eat Argox label printer, just still can not send anything to her.
The model is Argox OS214 tt, ANPP and accepts PPLB.

Use a generic class for connection to serial devices, I used her for several fiscal printers and scales, is attached. All using the rxtx library.
This class can also read the response from the device as already used on scales and never had problems as well as on fiscal printers.

I watched the manual PPLA and saw more or less how it works but not able to test anything yet.
I can not do anything out of it and also I can not read your response.

Here's my test:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  
public class TestePPLA {  
public static void main(String[] args){  
    String porta="COM1";  
    int velocidade=9600;  
    int databits=8;  
    int stopbits=1;  
    int paridade=0;  
    int timeout=10;  
    try  
    {             
        String comando = "<STX>L<CR>121100001000050THIS LABEL IS MADE BY JIMMY<CR>E<CR>";  
        ComunicacaoSerial comunica = ComunicacaoSerial.getReference ();  
        comunica.conexao (porta,velocidade,databits,stopbits,paridade);  
        comunica.escritaPortaSerial (comando.getBytes());  

        Thread.sleep(timeout);  
        String resposta = new String (comunica.getDados());  

        comunica.fechaConexao();                  

        System.out.println(resposta);  
    }  
    catch(Exception ex)  
    {  
        ex.printStackTrace();  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro de comunica\u00e7\u00e3o com a impressora", "Testador", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
    }  

}  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For what you said, the problem is that you are sending a PPLA code to a PPLB printer, when you do this the printer simple do nothing. This is an example of a PPLB code:

```
N↵
A50,30,0,1,1,1,N,"This is font 1." ↵
A50,70,0,2,1,1,N,"This is font 2." ↵
A50,110,0,3,1,1,N,"This is font 3." ↵
A50,150,0,4,1,1,N,"This is font 4." ↵
A50,200,0,5,1,1,R,"FONT 5"↵
P1↵
```